# Invalid Column Name when copying database between instances

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using the Copy Database feature in SSMS. The source instance is v 2012, the target instance is v 2019.

I am able to copy other databases in the source instance to the target instance. This particular database fails.

This message is from the Windows Event Viewer on the target machine. "InnerException-->Invalid column name 'Description'." does not make sense because there is
a column with that name in one of the tables in the source database. I can't tell what table it's complaining about from the message in the Windows Event Log.

There is one table in the source database with a column called Description:
[image]

```
  Event Name: OnError
 Message: An error occurred while transferring data. See the inner exception for details.
StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferDatabasesUsingSMOTransfer()
InnerException-->Invalid column name 'Description'.
StackTrace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.ExecuteStatements(SqlConnection destinationConnection, IEnumerable`1 statements, SqlTransaction transaction)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
 Operator: NT Service\SQLAgent$MSSQLSERVER2019
 Source Name: CDW_IL-SERVER-001_MSSQLSERVER2012_IL-SERVER-002_MSSQLSERVER2019_8
 Source ID: {6FCAF562-8C02-4A7F-BDE0-9B985BE99BCB}
 Execution ID: {C9D1672E-366F-49C2-B98F-903B080DF36A}
 Start Time: 8/14/2020 9:11:21 AM
 End Time: 8/14/2020 9:11:21 AM
 Data Code: 0
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVwxEX5OkqI

Comment: `Description` is a reserved word. Sounds like the Copy Database wizard isn't using quoted identifiers properly. Try using another tool to copy that database.